# Rails 5 test server hanging

Tags: postgresql, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest, puma

I am in the process of upgrading a Rails 4.2 application to Rails 5.0. We are using `capybara-minitest-rails` for our feature tests. All of the feature tests are currently timing out. We are using `ruby 2.4.2p198`.

When using `gdb` to inspect the process I got the following output:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:185
185     ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S: No such file or directory.
```

I added `ActionDispatch::DebugLocks` middleware which gave me the following on `/rails/locks`

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@jilt/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `async_exec'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@jilt/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `block in exec_no_cache'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@jilt/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:590:in `block in log'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@jilt/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@jilt/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:583:in `log'
...
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@jilt/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@jilt/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@jilt/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@jilt/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@jilt/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@jilt/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I have swapped out puma with thin and I still get the same issue. Trying to force puma to run with 1 process and 1 thread, as well as setting `eager_load=true` have yielded no positive results.

Comment: You actually want puma to use 0 processes  (workers) and 1 or more threads, as needed for simultaneous requests (so it runs in process).   If you just set `Capybara.server = :puma` without registering your own server, the capybara default is 0 workers and 4 threads - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara.rb#L451.  Beyond that do you happen to be using any active record connection sharing patches, or are you using database cleaner and truncation/deletion? –

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?